# If an element is not in the set difference $A\setminus B \: \:?$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Given two sets$$A=\{1,3,5\}\quad,\quad B=\{1,3,8\}.$$ Then I compute the $A\setminus B=\{5\}.$

But my book$^\dagger$said: ... . *Also, observe that $x\notin A\setminus B$ does not mean that $x\notin A\lor x\in B$. Why?*

I don't know how to explain the **Why**, please give me some example.

---

$^\dagger$*[a friendly introduction to analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130457965), second edition, page $4$.*

**EDIT**: My intuition tells me that it does mean that. I guess there is some special case about null-set or about the restriction of the universal set.

Comment: Right -- Lela Hatami's answer gives you the right concept; ignore the book's question -- it's either a typo or worse.

Comment: angryavian was the first user to comment on your question, but apparently, that comment was deleted (presumably by angryavian). I edited my comment to point to Lela Hatami's answer instead.

Comment: @quasi Thank you, But my name is Leila with $i$

Comment: @Leila Hatami -- sorry; I was careless.

Comment: @quasi Your welcome. Thanks again...

Comment: @Leila: Do not add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems wrong:

$x \in A\setminus B \iff x\in A \cap B' \iff x \in A \wedge x\notin B$

So

$x \notin A\setminus B \iff x \notin A \: \vee \: x\in B$

Answer (score 0):

Well, by definition the set $A \setminus B$ is the set of all elements $x$ that are in $A$ but not in $B$. I.e. $$x \in A \setminus B \iff x \in A \wedge x \notin B.$$ Note that $x \notin A \setminus B$ is equivalent, by DeMorgan’s Laws, to $$\neg (x \in A \setminus B) \sim \neg (x \in A \wedge x \notin B) \sim (x \notin A \vee x \in A).$$

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the identity $A\setminus B =A \cap B^c$, where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$ with respect to the universe, say $U$ Then $$ x \notin A \setminus B \iff x \notin A \cap B^c.$$ Applying DeMorgan’s laws (in the “set form” one gets $$ x \notin A \cap B^c \iff x \in (A \cup B)^c \iff x \in A^c \cap B,$$ this is, $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$.